# Run sync code in async code - promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Im using the following code with promises, the thing which bother me is that I use `readdirsync` and 
`fs.statSync`  inside promise, could it be wrong , I ask it since currently it works as expected but I wonder
If I can came into issue’s .or there is better way to write it?

What I did is extract root folder and then I extract the Childs

```
function unzip(filePath, rootP, fileN) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        extract(filePath, {dir: rootP, defaultDirMode: '0777'}, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            fs.readdirSync(path.join(rootP, fileN
)).forEach((file) => {
                const zipPath = path.join(rootP, fileN
, file);
                if (fs.statSync(zipPath).isFile()) {
                    if (path.extname(file) === '.zip') {
                        let name = path.parse(file).name;
                        let rPath = path.join(rootP, fileN)
                        return unzipChilds(zipPath, rPath, name)
                            .then(() => {
                                return resolve(“Done");
                            });
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Only you can tell us why you're using `fs.statSync()` and `fs.readdirSync()` instead of their asynchronous versions.  If this is server-based code, then all synchronous file I/O is very bad for the scalability of your server and only asynchronous I/O should be used.  If this is just some script you're using that doesn't care about scalability, then it doesn't really matter what you use.

Comment: Wrapping a bunch of stuff like this in a promise is not the best way to use promises because it's very easy to make mistakes, particularly with error handling and, indeed your code has a bunch of issues with error handling.

Comment: This is a server type code and I use it to read a directory and find all the directory inside with files type zip, type zip like `app1.zip` otherwise continue

Comment: @jfriend00 - This is the reason that I didnt sure about it :) , can you suggest a better way ?

Comment: @jfriend00 - btw, I use bluebird with promisify to fs , this can help here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Promises and `async/await` for all your logic flow like this:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const extractAsync = Promise.promisify(extract);

async function unzip(filePath, rootP, fileN) {
    await extractAsync(filePath, {dir: rootP, defaultDirMode: '0777'});
    let files = await fs.readdirAsync(path.join(rootP, fileN));
    for (let file of files) {
        const zipPath = path.join(rootP, fileN, file);
        let stats = await fs.statAsync(zipPath);
        if (stats.isFile() && path.extname(file) === '.zip') {
            let name = path.parse(file).name;
            let rPath = path.join(rootP, fileN);
            await unzipChilds(zipPath, rPath, name);
        }
    }
}

// usage:
unzip(...).then(() => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

Advantages:

1. Consistent and complete error handling.  Your version had multiple places where errors were not handled properly.
2. All asynchronous I/O so it won't interfere with scaling for a server.
3. `async/await` makes async logic flow simpler to follow

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it now :) , one question do I need to change function `unzipChilds` (since you use async ) ?

Comment: @JennyM - `unzipChilds()` must return a promise that resolves when its done.  You were already assuming that in your original code.  Also, I added some advantages of coding this way.  An `async` function returns a promise automatically.  You can `await` any promise whether it is from an `async` function or a manually returned promise - either will work.  So, you don't have to make `unzipChilds()` `async`.

Comment: Thanks, im debugging it now , one question, is there a way to import the for which run on any file , ie in files I got files like .Ds_store and other which is not .zip , is there a way to catch it before and save the loop iteration ?

Comment: @JennyM - Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I got erorr in the `stats.isFile()` since `stats` is undifened, any idea why? the `zipPath` contain value

Comment: @JennyM - Typo in my answer that I've fixed.  `fs.stat()` is supposed to be `fs.statAsync()`.  Also, `for (file of files)` is supposed to be `for (let file of files)`

Comment: Btw last question :) , where should I raise the errors ? is it sufficient like this ?

Comment: e.g. as you can see the extract can have error `extract(filePath, {dir: rootP}, (err)`

Comment: @JennyM - Extract has been promisified so if it has an error, it will return a promise that rejects and so `unzip()` will also return a rejected promise.  That's what the `.catch()` is for in the usage.  The error is caught there.  You can catch the error earlier if you want to do something different.